# Is there a underline setFontType in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, printing, jspdf

I know that there is 4 types of "setFontType" in jsPDF:

```
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.setFontType("italic");
doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.setFontType("bolditalic");
```

i tried some things but i can't find it, so is there a underline setFontType in jsPDF?

Comment: It's probably not setFontType, since underlining is not really a font variation. It's just drawing a line on (or just under) the baseline of the font. That said, I don't know jsPDF, so I don't know how it would be possible, if at all.

Comment: Indeed, i am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I'm using jsPDF inside of Nativescript, so I couldn't use 'addHTML.'

Adding a little to A Biswas first option I was able to get it to work for dynamic text size like this:

```
const textWidth = doc.getTextWidth(text);
doc.line(x, y, x + textWidth, y)
```

Comment: how to get the `text` variable to use as param in `getTextWidth` from creating a text element?

Comment: ah sorry just saw this. Not sure what you're asking. I have this wrapped in a function that takes text as a param. All my text comes from data we have stored. If you have html then you may be able to use `.addHtml`

Comment: I was asking as when i create a text element in jspdf I get returned a number rather than an object. so when I use `getTextWidth` it errrored out

Comment: `const textWidth = doc.getTextWidth("copy your actual text here")`

Answer (score 9):

I know this is late but i have a solution for this , you can do this in 2 ways :-

First you can use the inbuilt "line" option to draw a line below your text :-

```
doc.line(x-from,y-from,x-to,y-to);
```

Second you can display your text in html and then use the option to print html in your jspdf config for eg:-

```
<div id="disptext">
    <div class="underText">Hello</div>
</div>
<br/>
<input type='button' value='download' id='downP' />

<style>
.underText { text-decoration: underline;}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#downP').on('click', function() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

        pdf.addHTML($('#disptext')[0], function() {
            pdf.save('text.pdf');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

`doc.setFont("serif", "italic")`